# Get Request from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am really new with AWS. I got a task to get request from this link : https://s3.amazonaws.com , but it shows Access Denied. and Here is the result I got. Please help me to getObject data from the link

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>FF91410354571103</RequestId>
<HostId>
4KESrzSjgbNG+gURnW2d5PKiyDIUoesZoySaDKfSk6OVNtEi3j2KIrwVXrFXQ2HR
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to enable access to the s3 objects for public.
You can either add bucket policy for public access through aws console, which will enable public access to all files in the bucket [check this link](https://ariejan.net/2010/12/24/public-readable-amazon-s3-bucket-policy/) or set permission for each file that needs to be publicly accessible through aws console. When you click on the file you will see properties tab on the right side where you can set read access for everyone in permission setting.

[image: Sample permission s3]

Comment: So, the company share me the resource URL and I need to Get Request or permission, to get access into the content.

Comment: Do you have access to the console?

Comment: This is the only instruction I got.In order to access the instructions for submitting your file, you must GET the Parentfolder/2014_09/alias_54175575bedff resource from this web service:
https://s3.amazonaws.com

Comment: You should now what the bucket name is and if the objects are set to be accessed publicly or not.